# C#/C++ Calling C++ application, and getting output

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to make a C++ app, which returns a result to the C# app, which can be displayed, or maybe printed to the console.

For example, in my C++ file:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    // code
    some_method_to_return_result("result");
}
```

And in my C# app

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("exec.exe", "arguments");
some_method_to_get_result();
```

How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The best approach is to organize your C++ app as a dll and call this dll from the .NET process (C#). In this case you will have just one process. Calls from C# to C++ are very effective. Marshalling data in some cases can be tricky. In simple cases it is straightforward. Keep your data formats simple.

Prototype of your C++ function should look in C# like this:

```
[DllImport("avifil32.dll")]
private static extern void AVIFileInit();
```

Search for `C# dllimport` and `C# extern` for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're slightly confused about what information is available when you spawn a process in C#. You can't just directly call a C++ method you need a bunch of ugly interop code that I don't know about. What you can get from your C++ app is main's return code (either 1 or 0). Something like the following will make it so `result` holds the return status of your C++ app after it's execution has completed.

```
Process P = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("exec.exe", "arguments");
P.WaitForExit();
int result = P.ExitCode;
```

If you want to get other data from your C++ app you need to do some research on Marshalling which I'm not really knowledgeable on but I think this msdn article might be a good starting point; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C++ write your result to standard output:

```
std::cout << "result";
```

In C# use `Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine` or similar way to grab the standard output of C++ application.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but probably the easiest would be to write to some file in your c++ code, and read from it in your c# code:

```
//c++
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  ofstream fileToWrite;
  fileToWrite.open ("file.txt");
  fileToWrite << some_method_to_return_result("result");
  fileToWrite.close();
}

//c#
string data;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        data = reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
using (Process p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "filename.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "params";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // use CreateProcess
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // get stdout
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;  // get stderr
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    p.Start();

    string line;
    while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }

    if (!p.StandardError.EndOfStream)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
    }

}
```

btw, this code was extracted from a real-world app which I wrote a long time ago.